# Assign an array in a constructor

Tags: c++

in a class 
i have a public attribute TissueCompartments:

```
class Diver {
public:
    TissueCompartments tissueCompartments[16];
    Diver();
    Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments tissueCompartments[16]);
    virtual ~Diver();
};
```

and i have a constructor

```
Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments tissueCompartments[16]) {
    this->tissueCompartments=tissueCompartments;
}
```

i get this error:
 error: incompatible types in assignment of 'TissueCompartments*' to 'TissueCompartments [16]'

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are not assignable.  Do this instead in your constructor body:

```
#include <algorithm>
//..
Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments* tC)
{
    std::copy(tC, tC + 16, tissueCompartments);
    //...
}
```

Also, please be aware that this declaration:

```
Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments tissueCompartments[16])
```

is no different than this:

```
Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments* tissueCompartments)
```

Arrays decay to pointers, even when you place `[16]` in your parameter.  So that `[16]` has absolutely no effect (except to aid in letting you know it is an array of 16 that is being referred to).

Please also note that the `TissueCompartment` type needs to be an assignable type before doing any of these changes.

Comment: Let's hope `TissueCompartements` are assignable.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Yes, that too.  Those types must be assignable.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can't be assigned. Another thing which trips people up is the fact that functions can't take arrays by value - the compiler [implicitly decays array arguments to pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_to_pointer_decay). If you want an array with value semantics, use `std::array`.

```
class Diver {
public:
    std::array<TissueCompartments, 16> tissueCompartments;
    Diver();
    Diver(const Diver& orig, std::array<TissueCompartments, 16> tissueCompartments);
    virtual ~Diver();
};

Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, std::array<TissueCompartments, 16> tissueCompartments) {
    this->tissueCompartments=tissueCompartments;
}
```

Comment: Your changed code needlessly assumes `TissueCompartments` are assignable.

Answer (score 1):

While arrays aren't assignable, you can get around that limitation in your example easily, using a brace-initializer.
I used constructor-delegation and [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) due to constructive laziness:

```
#include <utility>

template<size_t... i> Diver::Diver<i...>(const Diver& orig,
        TissueCompartments tissueCompartments, std::index_sequence<i...>)
    : tissueCompartments{tissueCompartments[i]...}
{}

Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, TissueCompartments tissueCompartments[16])
    : Diver(orig, tissueCompartments, std::make_index_sequence(16) {}
```

The helpers are C++14, but only use C++11 features.

Answer (score 0):

As with any question involving arrays, your first thought should be to stop using arrays, and use `vector` instead.

```
#include <vector>
class Diver {
public:
    std::vector<TissueCompartments> tissueCompartments;
    Diver();
    Diver(const Diver& orig, std::vector<TissueCompartments> tissueCompartments);
    virtual ~Diver();
};
```

then you can do:

```
Diver::Diver(const Diver& orig, std::vector<TissueCompartments> tissueCompartments) {
    this->tissueCompartments=tissueCompartments;
}
```

and, if you're using C++11, you should be able to construct a Diver with an initializer list, assuming that a Diver is constructed by an int and a string:

```
Diver d{ {1,"hi"}, {2,"hi"}, {3,"hi"}, {4,"hi"}
       , {5,"hi"}, {6,"hi"}, {7,"hi"}, {8,"hi"}
       , {9,"hi"}, {10,"hi"}, {11,"hi"}, {12,"hi"}
       , {13,"hi"}, {14,"hi"}, {15,"hi"}, {16,"hi"}
       };
```